# What is the name for the grammatical figure, where the present tense is substituted for a past event?

Tags: past-tense, present-tense

I am preparing a book for publication which contains the following passage:

> Stromberg in *Religious Liberalism in Eighteenth-Century England*
>   (1954) noted that 'the critical moment in the emergence of a positive
>   spirit of reform...consisted in the awareness of evil as being social
>   and remediable. *It begins about 1750*.'

My proof reader (my wife) has picked this out suggesting it should be the past tense. However if I say *It began about 1750* it seems to convey too much certainty about the exact date. I just want to convey an impression of it being something which emerges in the mid-eighteenth century. I believe use of the present tense is the way to go.

But what is this artifice called, this use of the present to convey mild uncertainty?

Comment: Why do you believe that *about* doesn't give you the vagueness you seek?

Comment: Your proofreader might have missed the closing quotation mark. :)

Comment: I don't think there's any hint of uncertainty in the tense.

Comment: @Tim Romano Not uncertainty as to fact, but vagueness as to exact timing.

Comment: @WS2: I don't think there's any vagueness or uncertainty in the tense. There's no coloration in that regard versus the simple past.  Compare:  "Washington's troops suffer terribly in the freezing cold at Valley Forge." or "It begins on October 29, 1929 with the collapse of the stock market."

Comment: To convey a sense of uncertainty, you should probably 1) get rid of the phrase "critical moment" (which admittedly is not your phrase, but it undermines your intention so it seems like you need to deal with it), and 2) just say something like "this transition began in the mid-eighteenth century."

Comment: @KenWilliams The date given has no bearing on the *critical moment*. The latter describes the point at which *a positive spirit of reform occurs* i.e. when *the awareness of evil as being social and remedial* happens. *Critical moment* would still have been appropriately used, had no date been proposed.

Comment: @WS2 [Part of] what I mean is that **moments** don't *begin*, they *occur*.  They are instants, not periods with durations.  **Periods** begin.  I got pretty confused by this, because I assumed your "it" refers to "the critical moment" and it seems a mismatch to say a moment begins.  That's why I changed "it" to "this transition" - a transition can have a beginning and an end.

Comment: @TimRomano I'm beginning to think there is something in what you are saying here - and that it is simply a dramatic artifice. But it does seem to tone down what might appear an excess of dogmatism. To me it is the difference between stating something and suggesting something. What do you think it does?

Comment: @KenWilliams As you rightly point out, this is not my work, but that of an author called Stromberg. I think there is no doubt that *begins* is apt, because it will not have been something that happened across society in a *moment*. The whole is in quotation marks in my piece, so I do not intend to change what he said. But I do see what you mean, and it may have been better had he said *the transition begins*. But I defend his use of *moment* as metaphorical. Clearly it didn't happen in an instant.

Comment: I don't think the historical present casts things in a tentative light, at least not in historical narratives in academic style. It confers a kind of immediacy upon the past event; it is a sort of *reportage* that puts the audience there at the scene, so to speak, as events unfold. In literary works it can produce an entirely different effect, a kind of liminal state or dreaminess in which the narrator "disappears" and the events seem to take on a life of their own, as a *tableau vivant*.

Comment: @TimRomano Very interesting, though it is not entirely how I see it. I am wondering if this has been discussed as a question here.

Comment: This seems an exact duplicate of 'What is the term called for writing in present tense even though the text is in past tense?', though the term 'historic present' isn't given there. That thread itself was closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is called the **[historic present](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_present)**. It is also called *historical present*, *dramatic present, narrative present*, or *praesens historicum* in Latin. It is a perfectly fine construction, although it should be used in moderation so as not to draw the ire of style books.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. It has persuaded my wife. Congratulations.

Comment: It's a fine construction.  It *does not* convey the sense of uncertainty you seem to be seeking, though.  All it does is temporarily place the listener in the past.  To my ears, both your options have the same uncertainty.

Comment: @WS2: I take it that is a rare occurrence? I should congratulate you, probably!

Comment: [Historic present comes up on the Lexicon Valley podcast](http://www.slate.com/articles/podcasts/lexicon_valley/2012/07/lexicon_valley_the_historical_present_in_seinfeld_and_the_novels_of_charlotte_bronte.html). I recommend listening to it.

Comment: "It should be used in moderation" -- unless your name is Damon Runyon.