# the simple present tense

Tags: grammaticality

Why is *say* simple present, and not *said*? This isn't a repeated action, nor is it a general truth.

What sense or meaning was the writer going to express?

> American Airlines and Alaska Airlines **say** they will cooperate more closely on West Coast service, including new American flights from Seattle to India's technology hub in Bangalore. [emphasis added]

[American and Alaska strike deal around Seattle flights](https://www.yahoo.com/news/american-alaska-strike-deal-around-001639123.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the name for the grammatical figure, where the present tense is substituted for a past event?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/307730/what-is-the-name-for-the-grammatical-figure-where-the-present-tense-is-substitu) This device is called the historic present, dramatic present, or narrative present. Here, the last term seems the most appropriate; it is used here to show a still-obtaining situation, and give a sense of immediacy / ongoing concern.

Comment: The use of the present tense (_says_) here is a typical example of _journalese_. You will notice that the headline also uses the present tense (_strike_) - specifically _headlinese_. More here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headlinese

Comment: @Edward Ashworth I searched a bit about immediacy/ongoing concern. It seems like with"the simple presense" the past action is made sound like the present action to draw more attension from the public. So is that how the present tense on a spot where a verb should be in other tenses gives a sense of immediacy? I don't quit get "show a still-obtaining situation and give a sense of ongoing concern".Could you explain it ?