# Using present tense in past tense narration

Tags: past-tense, writing, present-tense

Is it grammatically correct to use the present tense in fiction that's narrated in the past tense? Sometimes, as a writer, you add "general statements" into your narrative. Example:

> But random chance just didn’t sit right with him. Nothing in the world
> is truly random.

The second sentence is just a general statement, it isn't an event that happens. Will "Nothing in the world was truly random" be the correct version, or maybe both versions are acceptable?

Another example:

> Derek thought of a simple plan - he'll leave the Maglite far away from
> the tunnel through which the creature comes. The boy himself will hide
> behind stalagmites. Then he'll slip away behind his opponent's back
> while it inspects the "bait". This course of action should allow him
> to avoid any risks whatsoever.

In this case, the narrative describes the plan of action in the present tense even if the rest of it is told in the past tense. Would it be grammatically acceptable?

When it comes to writing fiction in the past simple, I didn't find any decent guides that would mention how different times should interact in the narrative.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the name for the grammatical figure, where the present tense is substituted for a past event?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/307730/what-is-the-name-for-the-grammatical-figure-where-the-present-tense-is-substitu)

Comment: There is nothing ungrammatical in your extracts. Such tense shifts are common in _free indirect speech_: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_indirect_speech

Comment: Your sentences are clear and grammatical. Use of the historic present is a matter of style and taste rather than grammar. The historic present is often over-used by over-enthusiastic historians desperate to imbue a plain account of the past with the exciting immediacy of the present, but your examples seem well-contrived.