# Why do we use "hear" in a present time in a sentence with a past meaning?

Tags: grammar, past-tense, present-tense

I came across  this sentence from R. Murphy's grammar book:

> I hear Sarah won some money. What is she going to do with it.

Could you tell me please why 'hear' is in a present form not in past?

Comment: It is idiomatic usage, in the sentence ***hear*** means:  ***to be told information about something***:  *I hear (that) you're leaving.* http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hear - I hear, I am told (now) that she won some money (in the past).

Comment: It indicates that the source is a rumor (or at least unidentified). It corresponds to "People are saying that Sarah won some money".

Comment: Its similar to "*They say Sarah won some money*"

Comment: @Josh - "*I am **told***..." is generally used when you are describing to someone *now* something that you have heard/been told in the recent past (i.e. not 'now').

Comment: @Dan - Yes, and that is what  "I hear" means in the sentence.

Comment: Hear, here, also means not specific (If you heard in the past, when was it? Who knows!) and possibly repeated (this is what am hearing from more than one source.)

Comment: It's an idiomatic, everyday example of the [dramatic present](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_present). From the Wikipedia article: << More recently, analysts of its use in conversation have argued that it functions not by making an event present, but by marking segments of a narrative, foregrounding events (that is, signalling that one event is particularly important, relative to others) and marking a shift to evaluation (Brinton 1992: 221). >>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use a present-tense verb when writing about a past event?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/392588/can-i-use-a-present-tense-verb-when-writing-about-a-past-event)